# why is my ajax unable to get the currently typed string in the input form?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form, then I placed some data from the table to each of the input forms value attribute. now my problem is, whenever i typed something new to the input form, to update the data, it's unable to pick up the currently typed string, am not sure how to solve this, because I think it is picking up the value echoed out instead of the currently typed string when on this update page,

here's my front-end

```
    <fieldset id="personaldetails">
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    Resume Title: <input type="text" name="resumetitle" id="resumetitle" value="<?php echo $v['ResumeTitle']; ?>" size="50" maxlength="50" /><br />
    Name: <input type="text" name="cvname" id="cvname" size="30" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo $v['Name']; ?>" /><br />
    DOB: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dob" value="<?php $date = new DateTime($v['DOB']); echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); ?>" /><br />
    Gender:  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-male" value="1" <?php if($v['Gender'] == 1){ echo "checked"; } ?>/> <b>Male</b> |
     <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-female" value="0" <?php if($v['Gender'] == 0){ echo "checked"; } ?>/> <b>Female</b><br /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="cvid" id="cvid" value="<?php echo $v['ResumeID']; ?>" />
    <button name="pdetails" id="pdetails">Update</button>
    </fieldset><br /><br />
```

//here's my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var resumetitle = $('#resumetitle').val();
 var cvid = $('input[type="hidden"]').val();
 var name = $('#cvname').val();
 var dob = $('#datepicker').val();
 var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();


$('button#pdetails').click(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.resumeupdate.php",
      data: "resumeid="+cvid+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&gender="+gender,
      success: function(){
        //window.location = "resumeview.php?cvid="+cvid;
      },
   });
});


});
```

//here's my php code

```
require 'class.resume.php';

$db = new Resume();

if(isset($_POST['resumetitle']) || isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['dob']) ||
   isset($_POST['gender']) || isset($_POST['cvid'])){
    $result =  $db->updatepdetails($_POST['resumetitle'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['dob'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['cvid']);
    if($result){
      echo "success!";
    } else {
      echo "failed! ".$db->error;
    }
   }
```

Comment: It seems the answer you marked as correct didn't solve your problem. Did you try my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only reading the values on document ready, move that code into the click event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('button#pdetails').click(function(){
     var resumetitle = $('#resumetitle').val();
     var cvid = $('input[type="hidden"]').val();
     var name = $('#cvname').val();
     var dob = $('#datepicker').val();
     var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "classes/ajax.resumeupdate.php",
       data: "resumeid="+cvid+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&gender="+gender,
       success: function(){
           //window.location = "resumeview.php?cvid="+cvid;
       },
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: ok am getting the values correct now..but it fails to update the table data..how to output the mysql error at the firebug console response tab ?..because all i can see in the response was the word "failed!"

Comment: Try my code instead. The code above will make the update fail on inputs including special characters (like: '&;?") because there is no encoding going on.

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript is resolving the form values just once (on page load), so if you enter something after the page has loaded, the variables don't change.

You can simply calculate the values inside the Ajax callback instead. But what you really should do is use jQuery's [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function, which creates a standard `a=1&b=2&c=3` querystring including the (properly escaped) form data:

```
$(function(){
  $('button#pdetails').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.resumeupdate.php",
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success: function(){
        //window.location = "resumeview.php?cvid="+cvid;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also note that you had a trailing comma after the success function - this [will fail in IE](https://grepular.com/JavaScript_Comma_Quirk) so I've changed that as well.

Comment: I updated the code, now you can just drop it in. If your form has an ID (like `<form id="some_form">`), use `$('form#some_form').serialize()`